# MPU 9250 driver in Linux: what's the temperature unit?

Tags: linux-kernel, sensors

Can someone please tell me what is the temperature unit in MPU 9250 linux driver?

I've looked at the source here https://github.com/NoelMacwan/Kernel-10.4.1.B.0.101/blob/master/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu/inv_mpu_core.c#L1112 and in the accompanying README file and I have not got a clue, what sort of temperature I get from the driver.

Comment: Why do you look at the driver code while from your question you need to look into datasheet? And better to use Elixir site for the sources of Linux kernel: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source

Comment: @0andriy Because I've read the datasheet, and I don't understand how exactly the driver follows it. As for the site use: why is it better? What if the driver I use was not upstreamed (in my not so latest kernel)?

Comment: If you didn't find a driver it doesn't mean there is none in upstream. Check http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/imu/inv_mpu6050